# Replace action of swipe to delete by clicking on a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a tableview with a label and two buttons on each cell. At the moment I have this code that does a swipe to delete.

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [appointments removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];  // manipulate your data structure.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
       NSLog(@"row deleted");  // Do whatever other UI updating you need to do.
    }
}
```

This code gets executing when I swipe. But I want it to execute when a button is pressed. The button is linked with the following IBAction.

```
- (IBAction)deleteRow:(id)sender {
  //Delete row
}
```

One thing to keep in mind. I want that the delete button slides like when you swiped to delete.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your button is in the cell, you could set its tag property to the indexPath.row value and assign it the deleteRow:(id)sender method for target via  `-(void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents` In order to have the button slide, you may need to implement the panGestureRecognizer. I may be wrong about this but the idea should be pretty much to detect the touch locations & slide the button (setting its frame as you slide). And you may need to disable swipe to delete on the table if your intention is to delete by sliding the button.