# swipe to delete action replaced by button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace action of swipe to delete by clicking on a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641362/replace-action-of-swipe-to-delete-by-clicking-on-a-button)

I have the following code.

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [appointments removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];  // manipulate your data structure.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
       NSLog(@"row deleted");  // Do whatever other UI updating you need to do.
    }
}
```

This piece of code is going to be execute when I swipe on the cell. But what I want is that this code executes when I press a button in my custom tableview cell. Like you can see on the screenshot below I have 2 buttons on my tableview.

[image]

When the user presses the 'X' button the delete button should roll out like when you swipe the cell. I have the following action attached to my cell.

```
-(IBAction) deleteAppointment:(id) sender{
   //show swipe delete button
}
```

And attached it in my cellForRowAtIndex at the following way.

```
cell.deleteAppointment.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.deleteAppointment addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteAppointment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just addTarget with button in your cell and set tag to every button like bellow..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /////your code
    UIButton *btnClose = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 7, 20, 20)];
    btnClose.tag = indexPath.row;
    [btnClose setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"closeImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnClose addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteAppointment:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:btnClose];
    return cell;
}
```

and in the method see like this...

```
    - (IBAction)deleteAppointment:(id)sender {

            // here bellow code for swipe the close button in cell
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
            int SelectedRowNo = btn.tag;
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
            [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(btn.frame.origin.x - 50, btn.frame.origin.y, btn.frame.size.width, btn.frame.size.height)];
            [UIView commitAnimations];

            //// here bellow code for delete raw from table
            /*
             [appointments removeObjectAtIndex: SelectedRowNo];
             UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
             NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [yourTableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
             [yourTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: clickedButtonPath]
             withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
             NSLog(@"row deleted");  // Do whatever other UI updating you need to do.
             */
}
```

i hope this help you..

Comment: Where should I put this code ?

Comment: in your cellForRowAtIndexPath  method with tag so you can easily findout which raw clciked here..

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I have in mind. What I want is that when I press the 'x' button. A button should slide into my cell like the swipe to delete action. Do you know what I mean ?

Comment: oh ok then here if possible then try my code wait i will post the code dude..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20386/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-paras-joshi)